# Increasing tomcat memory using puppet

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, puppet

I'm trying to install/setup tomcat7 using puppet.

I haven't found a module that lets me set up the max heap memory.

So I've been trying to inject the line "CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx2048m" into the catalina.sh file.

I'm not really sure what the best way to do this in though. I looked into the file_line resource, but I don't know how to make it insert in the middle of the catalina.sh file.

Any suggestions welcomed.

Update:
Some people suggested templates, but I don't need to parameterize anything. I want to be able to take whatever catalina.sh that the tomcat install produces and inject a line into it. If I used templates, or replaced the file with a modified copy, then the next tomcat I install may have a different catalina.sh, and this would overwrite the new file format.

Maybe what I need is a way to insert a line AFTER another line.
I believe I can insert "CATALINA_OPTS=" right after the #!/bin/bash line. Is this possible?

Comment: templates my man ! use templates...

Answer (score 3):

Use file_line's `matches` parameter, so existing CATALINA_OPTS line in original file will be replaced with the new line.

```
  file_line { "Tomcat Memory":
    line => "CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx2048m",
    path=> "/route/to/catalina.sh",
    notify =>Service['tomcat'],
    match => "CATALINA_OPTS=.*",
  }
```

Comment: Not sure this will work. First, I don't want to replace the CATALINA_OPTS on that line so I'd really want to do something like "CATALINA_OPTS=$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx2048m". But this won't work either because "CATALINA_OPTS=.*" appears in several places in catalina.sh

Comment: Can I do something more sophisticated like, replace the first instance of "CATALINA_OPTS=.*"...? or is that what it's already doing?

Answer (score 3):

I run to the same issue. I'm installing tomcat using puppetlabs/tomcat, but there is not a word about the way to manage the memory size.

However there is a way to manage the setenv.sh which let you set the JAVA

Here is an example that should do what you want:

```
  include  'java'
  class { 'tomcat':
    install_from_source => true,
  }

  tomcat::instance{ 'default':
    source_url    => 'http://mirror.nexcess.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.23/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.23.tar.gz',
  } ->
  tomcat::setenv::entry {'JAVA_OPTS':
    value => "-Xmx256m",
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

On our debian system I used the following entry as a variant to "Raul Andres" answer.

```
file_line { "Tomcat Memory":
  line => 'JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"',
  path=> "/etc/default/tomcat8",
  notify => Service['tomcat8'],
  match => "^JAVA_OPTS=.*",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would completely control the file with a template. It is fairly easy to do. Start with defining the file :

```
class your_module_name ($memory='2048m') {
    file { '/where/is/catalina.sh':
        owner   => 'root',
        group   => 'root',
        mode    => '0755',
        content => template('your_module_name/catalina.sh.erb');
    }
}
```

Now, copy the current version of `catalina.sh` into `modules/your_module_name/templates/catalina.sh.erb`. Just add the following line to it:

```
CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx<%=memory%>
```

And it should work like a charm.

Comment: I'm not well versed in puppet's template. Any chance you could help me write one?

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Comment: If I understand templates correctly, it just lets me parameterize a file, but I don't need to parameterize anything. I can already take a copy of the catalina.sh that the current tomcat install produces, add a static CATALINA_OPTS value, and then make sure to replace it during the next install. But the problem is what if the next version of tomcat I install doesn't use the same catalina.sh (ie has different logic or additionnal params), then I'd be overwriting it with an old version of the file.

Comment: btw, I appreciate the advice. And I apologize if I'm not understanding the solution better if it in fact works

Comment: No, you are right. Is that a packaged tomcat ? In that case there often is a file that you can edit to do just that (on debian based distros it's in `/etc/default`) ? Your cue is usage of the `source` or `.` commands in the shell script.

Comment: According to `https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/bin/catalina.sh`, you just need to create a file at `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh`, with the proper environment variable set up.

Comment: Another option is just to set it before calling `catalina.sh`.

Comment: I'm going to try the setenv.sh route. I believe I've used it before with success. Thanks for reminding me

Comment: Using file_line to add CATALINA_OPTS to setenv.sh worked for me. I supposed I could also use templates for this. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the puppetlabs/tomcat module, the correct way to do this is using the `tomcat::setenv::entry` class.

If you're not using puppetlabs/tomcat, the correct way to do this is still using the `setenv.sh` file, **not** by editing `catalina.sh` directly. Since the former doesn't exist by default it should be easy to manage via puppet, either using `stdlib::file_line` or the builtin `file` resource.

Finally, you should be editing the `CATALINA_OPTS` variable, which only applies to tomcat, as opposed to `JAVA_OPTS`, which will be applied to any subprogram that might be spawned by one of your tomcat apps and probably doesn't have the same memory requirements as tomcat itself.